# The usage of "who knows"

Tags: grammaticality, rhetoric, errors

Is the second sentence correct English? What is the grammatical role and meaning of "who knows how many jobs"?

> ...Traditional cars happen to be human sized to transport humans but tiny autos can work in wear houses [*sic*] and gigantic autos can work in pit mines. Moving stuff around is ***who knows* how many jobs but the transportation industry employs about three million people.**

[Source: "Humans Need Not Apply"](http://www.cgpgrey.com/blog/humans-need-not-apply)

Comment: This question has so many issues it is difficult to know where to start. If you checked the spelling and grammar, reduced it to one question that is not proofreading, and made clear what you are actually asking, it might fit on English Language Learners. But you yourself need to make more effort before asking strangers for help.

Comment: It's a rather clunky colloquial usage. If you replace ***who / God / Christ knows how much / many*** with a straightforward equivalent, you'll see what a mess it is: *Moving stuff around is **an unknown number** of jobs but the transportation industry employs about three million people.* Not a style you'd really want to emulate.

Comment: @TimLymington These sentences are from the script of a very popular video called "human need not apply." I was asking if that second sentence  grammatically makes sense.

Comment: wear houses? really?

Comment: Technically speaking, ***Human** need not apply* could be seen as a syntactically valid variation on a theme, since things like ***Irish** need not apply* were quite common until more enlightened Anglophone countries banned such discrimination. But actually, the video you're referring to is called ***Humans** need not apply*, and I suspect only non-native speakers would change it the way you have.

Comment: Oh Yes. That's "Humans" need not apply.                                                                     I am not a native speaker and that's why I was seeking a good native's opinion about the grammar of another native's English narration, which by the way was delivering a very impressive message.

Comment: @Xanne .. that's funny. Yes actually he used "wear house" instead of "warehouse". When I was watching his video, it was so impressive. But when I carefully read his sentences, I was confused by the non-traditional expressions and exceptional style of some sentences. I began to be unsure about the author now.  This is the website: http://www.cgpgrey.com/blog/humans-need-not-apply

Comment: It's not what I would call good writing. There are a number of errors, spelling "warehouse", poor grammar: *But humans are smart-ly lazy*, missing hyphens,... Who transcribed this?

Comment: The video is easier to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Pq-S557XQU

Answer (score 3):

"Who-knows-how-many" is used as a substitute for **some number**. It is an example of a [placeholder](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/placeholder-names-thingamajigs-doohickeys-and-whatchamacallits) noun or word, or in this case, noun phrase

> I have read 7 books.
>
> I have read who-knows-how-many books.

Answer (score 0):

"who knows how many" is a way of saying you don't know a certain number.

> 100 people a year are treated for X medical condition, although since it doesn't have symptoms, *who knows how many are affected*.

You're more likely to hear this sentence spoken than read, as the "who knows how many" is a slight digression from the actual topic of the sentence.

But your sentence sounds strange without additional context because it sort of contradicts itself. If the industry employs 3m, *you do know how many*.

Here is an example that makes sense:

> Moving stuff around requires who knows how many jobs, but the industry *as a whole, which includes drivers, office staff, etc* employs about 3 million people.